# Should warnings about missing typename supressed in c++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, compiler-warnings

Warning messages like:

`missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name ... [-Wtypename-missing]`

and

`template argument for template type parameter must be a type; omitted 'typename' is a Microsoft extension [-Wmicrosoft-template]`

If I understand right c++20 relaxed the need for `typename`. Does this mean that these warnings are outdated? Or should I add the (annoying) `typename` whenever there is warning? (I'm using Visual Studio / Clang12 / std=C++20.)

Comment: Can you cite the (non-Microsoft) C++20 standard part you are referring to?

Comment: Have you tried `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wtypename-missing"` in one of your top-level headers? (And similarly for `-Wmicrosoft-template`.)

Comment: @AdrianMole It works if I do that. I don't know if it will lead to any actual bugs though. I don't know if these warnings are legit or deprecated.

Comment: @AdrianMole Did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the warning is useful. Fix your code.

C++20 relaxed the `typename` rules *a little bit*. But it's unrelated to this warning.

MSVC considers `typename` to be (almost?) completely optional, and is non-conforming in this regard. Clang apparently can do that too, for compatibility with MSVC. The warning says that your code is non-conforming, and might not work on other compilers (most notably on GCC).